# Elasticsearch - best query and index for partial and fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, partial, analyzer, fuzzy

I thought this scenario must be quite common, but I was unable to find the best way to do it.

I have a big dataset of products. All the products have this kind of schema:

```json
{
   "productID": 1,
   "productName": "Whatever",
   "productBoost": 1234
}
```

I have this problem to combine partial (query string) and fuzzy query.
What i have is about 1.5M records in an index which have listed the names od the product and the boost value- like the popularity value of the product(most common have higher popularity and less popular ones have less popularity).
For this i would like to use function score.

What i was trying to achieve is **search as you type**, with the function score and fuzziness.

I’m not sure if this is the best approach.

Current query i'm using is this:

```json
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "productName": {
                    "query": "word",
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "operator": "AND"
                }
            }
        },
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "productBoost",
            "factor": 1,
            "modifier": "square"
        }
    }
}
```

This is working kinda ok, but the problem is that i want products like:
**"Cabbage raw"**, to come up before **"Cabernet red wine"**, when i try to search for the string **"cab"** because the boost is way higher on **"Cabbage raw"**.
Another problem is when i search for the word "cabage" (typo of "cabagge"), there is only one product, and there are a lot of "cabagge" containing products.
If the query_string had the fuzziness with the wildcards, that would be ideal for this solution i think.

Also this is a match query so partial part is not working as well.

I tried using query_string, with the wildcards, but the downside of that is i can not use fuzziness for that kind of query.

Also i've tried nGrams and edge but i'm not sure how to implement it in this case scenario and how to combine the search score with the existing boost i have.

The only thing, that might even fix this issue, that i didn't try are suggesters.
I couldn't make them work with the function_score.

If anyone have any ideas on implementing this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: have you tried adding a sort by productName and productBoost value to the query?

Comment: Yes, but the sorting is handled by function_score. The thing i have problem with are the fuzzy query with the typos combined with the partial match.

Comment: You can use [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/search-explain.html) to get some idea of what exactly affects your score.

Comment: Did you check completion suggester? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester